# Number Picker in Access / VBA

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-access-2007

I am trying to put a number picker in a form in MS Access 2007. Here's an example of what I am trying to make:

[image]

I cannot find this in the default form controls, and have tried to make one myself using a listbox. Listboxes can be modified to look just like the number picker above, however the arrows only change the view, of the list, and not the actual selection (that is the value). For example, with the list box, if I have it range from 1 to 3, and default at 1 - when I change it to 2 via the arrows, the value of the listbox does not change, and is still one.

Does anyone know how to get a number picker in Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to create a list of numbers and allow users to change the value displayed (AND stored as the control's value) using up and down arrows, such that they select the next or previous in the list.

I would suggest creating a text box and two buttons.  Populate an array with the list of values.  When a button is clicked it would:

A. Find the position in the array of any value already entered into the text box (eg loaded from a database)

B.  Get the next or previous item from the array.

The array is populated as required (probably when the form is opened).

If you just need to allow the user to enter a whole integer number (ie a number spinner) you would do as follows:

Create one using a (locked) textbox and two buttons. Just add a textbox (name it something like txtValue) and two buttons (btnUp and btnDown), then add code like this to the Click event of those buttons:

```
Private Sub btnUp_Click()
  Me.txtValue = Nz(Me.txtValue, 0) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub btnDown_Click()
  Me.txtValue = Nz(Me.txtValue, 0) - 1
End Sub
```

You could add if statements to limit the data being entered

Or you can use a 3rd party control.

http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/controls/components/spin-button/index.html

There are probably more, but be aware that using these sorts of controls in Access is unsupported, and there is no guarantee moving forward that they will work in Access. You're far better off using the native methods described earlier.